# ELB Nginx redirect http to https

Tags: spring-boot, nginx, amazon-elb

So here is my config:

```
server {
      listen         80;
      server_name    *.example.com;
      if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = 'http') {            
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
        }
}
```

When I go to example.com nginx redirect me to https://example.com but the page is a stub nginx index.html.
If I go www.example.com it stays unsecure so it is not redirected at all.

What I am doing wrong? 
Thanks.

EDIT:
When I do like in this article: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redirect-http-https-elb/

return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri$http_x_forwarded_proto;

Then it is redirected https://example.com/http
And of course it is 404 cause http endpoint is stupid.

Comment: I have also tried this solution. It doesn't work as well. https://www.allcloud.io/how-to-force-https-behind-aws-elb/

Answer (score 1):

You really should avoid using "if" in nginx, it is a performance killer.

you should just use this :

```
server {
  listen      80;
  server_name *.example.com;

  ## redirect http to https ##
  return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

and define your "example.com" server.

if the elb is properly setup to send 443 request to example.com and if you have a listening socket on example.com:443 it will be fine.

Comment: Thanks @Requiem13. I tried what have you suggested but with no luck. I built a spring boot app that listens on 80th port. Then ELB is set to listen both on 443 and 80 and redirect to 80 of machine running my spring boot app.  Do you have any ideas? Maybe I misconfigured something?  thx.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not useful answer cause this solution leads to infinite loop. And amazon is explaining that in that article I have attached to the initial question.